# passing utf8 characters with html over URL?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to use ajax to send **user input** which **contains** HTML and utf8 characters(ex: chinese , japanese arabic characters) to a php script for it to store in database.

I normally escape() the html content first before placing it into url. however the escape is cauing the uft8 characters to become hex codes.

For example 
(ORIGINAL):

```
<div id="box">テスト</div>
```

After escaped:

```
 %3Cdiv%20id%3D%22box%22%3E%u30C6%u30B9%u30C8%3C/div%3E
```

Send to php script which php parse and save it into database(mysql , column type :text).

Php echo the saved data out:

```
<div id="box">%u30C6%u30B9%u30C8</div>
```

I also used this script in my php script to prevent php from adding a `\` before html's `"`

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    function undo_magic_quotes_array($array)
    {
        return is_array($array) ? array_map('undo_magic_quotes_array', $array) : str_replace("\\'", "'",
                                                                             str_replace("\\\"", "\"",
                                                                             str_replace("\\\\", "\\",
                                                                             str_replace("\\\x00", "\x00", $array))));
    }
    $_GET = undo_magic_quotes_array($_GET);
    $_POST = undo_magic_quotes_array($_POST);
    $_COOKIE = undo_magic_quotes_array($_COOKIE);
    $_FILES = undo_magic_quotes_array($_FILES);
    $_REQUEST = undo_magic_quotes_array($_REQUEST);
}
```

I'm not sure whether this script is causing it OR the javascript's escape() causing it?
Any ideas?

Comment: what does the $_GET parameter says? `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: Are you submitting the value/form via Javascript?

Comment: yes its from javascript , through ajax , to a php script

Comment: @Eun ,it shows : `%u30C6%u30B9%u30C8`

Comment: so its not an serverside issue, make sure javascript sends the right stuff, i am curious about that `/div` at the end. Try to base64 encode the data to be absolutly sure that the data is correct. Thats what I would do, then it could be possible to skip the escaping.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will do `urldecode()` for those requests automatically, but JavaScript's `escape()` is not equal to PHP's `urlencode()`. For example, `urlencode('テスト')` will output `"%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88"`, not `"%u30C6%u30B9%u30C8"`.

Try to use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `escape()` in JavaScript.

PS. In fact, this function is not totally equal to `urlencode()`, but it may solve your question =)